# php sql query returns multiple rows for each individual record, misuse of joins?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, group-by

I am trying to have my query return each record in my database once, the problem is if the listing has multiple images stored in a seperate table it returns multiple records (one for each image)

here is a snippet of my database layout (the data wrapped in ** are the primary keys)

```
tbl_listings => **listingID**,title,description,dateListed
tbl_images => **imageID**,filename
tbl_listing_image => **listingID**,**imageID**
```

this is my code

```
$stmt = $db->stmt_init();
if($stmt->prepare("SELECT l.listingID, l.title, l.description, l.dateListed, c.category, tn.townID, tn.town, i.filename
FROM tbl_listings AS l
LEFT JOIN tbl_listing_category AS lc ON lc.listingID = l.listingID
LEFT JOIN tbl_category AS c ON c.categoryID = lc.categoryID
LEFT JOIN tbl_listing_type AS lt ON lt.listingID = l.listingID
LEFT JOIN tbl_type AS t ON t.typeID = lt.typeID
LEFT JOIN tbl_listing_town AS ltn ON ltn.listingID = l.listingID
LEFT JOIN tbl_towns AS tn ON tn.townID = ltn.townID
LEFT JOIN tbl_listing_image AS li ON li.listingID = l.listingID
LEFT JOIN tbl_images AS i ON i.imageID = li.imageID
WHERE t.typeID =?"))
{
$type = 1;
$stmt->bind_param("i",$type);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id,$title,$desc,$date,$cat,$townID,$town,$image);
echo "<ul>";

while($stmt->fetch())
{
    $img = "images/listing/$id/$image";
    echo "<li><img src='$img' alt='$title' title='$title'>#".$id."<h4>" . $title . "</h4>" . $desc . "<br /><strong> Category:</strong> " . $cat . " - <strong>Location: </strong> - <strong> Posted On:</strong> " . date("i M Y",$date) . "</li><hr>";    
}
echo "</ul>";

$stmt->close();
```

which returns the following results (bearing in mind there is only 1 record in the tbl_listings table)

```
listingID   title        description    dateListed    category    townID    town    filename
1           listing 1    listing desc   1411240751    teaching    11        town a  image1.jpg
1           listing 1    listing desc   1411240751    teaching    11        town a  image2.jpg
1           listing 1    listing desc   1411240751    teaching    11        town a  image3.jpg
```

so the query is returning 3 records (one for each filename) even though its the same listing

so i tried adding a GROUP BY l.listingID to my query which returned just one record but it also only returned the first image like so

```
listingID   title        description    dateListed    category    townID    town    filename
1           listing 1    listing desc   1411240751    teaching    11        town a  image1.jpg
```

so my question is for each listing how can i return only 1 record but all of its associated images? do i need to run a seperate query within the while loop to get the images?

Would appreciate any help
Cheers

Comment: See the GROUP_CONCAT(expr) MySQL grouping function. Sorry, your SQL is a bit to long to write an answer with an example of which I can be certain it is correct. Anybody else?

Comment: @kiko software, thank you for your reply I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to list the filenames as a single field:

```
SELECT l.listingID, l.title, l.description, l.dateListed, c.category, tn.townID, tn.town, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(i.filename) as filenames
FROM tbl_listings AS l
LEFT JOIN tbl_listing_category AS lc ON lc.listingID = l.listingID
LEFT JOIN tbl_category AS c ON c.categoryID = lc.categoryID
LEFT JOIN tbl_listing_type AS lt ON lt.listingID = l.listingID
LEFT JOIN tbl_type AS t ON t.typeID = lt.typeID
LEFT JOIN tbl_listing_town AS ltn ON ltn.listingID = l.listingID
LEFT JOIN tbl_towns AS tn ON tn.townID = ltn.townID
LEFT JOIN tbl_listing_image AS li ON li.listingID = l.listingID
LEFT JOIN tbl_images AS i ON i.imageID = li.imageID
WHERE t.typeID =?
GROUP BY l.listingID
```

The advantage is that you have a single query with a single roundtrip time, so it's quite efficient. You do need to split those filenames again, of course, but that is trivial in PHP.

On the other hand, there is a maximum length `GROUP_CONCAT` can return, and if a category can have a lot of files, you might reach that limit.

Also, if any of the other tables also cause duplication, you might get each file name multiple times. This can be solved using `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT filename)`, so you're still safe, but if you want not only the file names, but also other properties of the file (type, owner?) you are stuck. In that case there is no shame in running a separate query for the filenames or other details that occur multiple times.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to discuss this in great detail, I will check it out tomorrow and let you know how I get on, appreciate your help

Comment: that has worked a treat!! thank you very much for your help. The maximum length hopefully wont be an issue as i will only be displaying 25 listings on my page at one time, so even if each of those has 10 images it wont be a massive amout of data. fingers crossed :)